# Should a WiX web installer and stand-alone installer both show up in Add/Remove programs?

Tags: wix, wix3.9

We have two WiX installers that use our own BA. One installer gets all the packages from the web, while the other gets all the packages from the exe. We call them "Web" and "Full" installers.

We have a case where a user might install one package from the web installer and a different package form the full installer. It probably won't happen often but it could happen. When the user does this, we have two entries in the Add/Remove programs control panel. Since we didn't name the installers differently, it looks like the installer is installed twice.

My question is, if the only difference between two installers created with WiX is the way the packages were acquired, shouldn't it just appear once in Add/Remove programs? Do I need to set a code somewhere to say it is the same installer?

I guess we could just name them differently so that a "Web" and a "Full" installer appeared in Add/Remove Programs, but when you run either one, both packages show up for uninstallation because both installers know about them. It's not like the web installer only shows the package that was installed through it and the full the package that was installed through it.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: What are the upgrade codes of the two `<Bundle...>` elements?

Comment: The upgrade codes are set to the same GUID. I thought maybe that would help but it didn't do anything regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a version upgrade scenario, using the same UpgradeCode for both `<Bundle...>` packages is enough to indicate both installers are the same product.  For example, if you first install package V1.0 and later install package V1.1 (where both packages use the same upgrade code) Package V1.1 replaces Package V1.0 in **Add/Remove Programs**.

Unfortunately the burn engine does not support same version upgrades. If you have different packages with the same upgrade code *and* the same version, both packages will appear in **Add/Remove Programs**. For more information on burn not supporting same version upgrades see: http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3746/.

Installing two different packages with the same upgrade code *and* version is well behaved. For example, if you install both packages and subsequently remove one of them, the resources in the first package remain installed, even though the same resources are also in the second package.

Installing two different packages with the same upgrade code *and* version, then later installing a third package with the same upgrade code but a higher version is also well behaved.  The third package replaces the first two packages!

Your suggestion of varying the name of the packages to differentiate them in **Add/Remove Programs** sounds the most pragmatic way forward. Having two entries does not appear to compromise the installation state, and upgrades appear to be handled without issues.

Comment: I raised WIX bug http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4800/ for the scenario of two entries in Add/Remove Programs when the UpgradeCode and Version are the same.

Comment: Turns out the new WIX issue raised duplicates http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3746/.

Comment: Thanks! I have added my comments to issue 3746 and set it back to untriaged. I am hoping that with my particular case, web-installer/full-installer scenario, they might up the priority but that's probably a long shot.